# User Memberships/Roles (ASP.NET) - Using XML instead of SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-membership

Is it possible to use XML as the database instead of SQL? Is there any info about this somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to [implement a custom Membership provider](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider). There are [many articles](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=asp.net+custom+membership+provider&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=b09b52e0d9b0a416) on this topic.

Comment: YAAAAAAAAAAAY @Darin fixed it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. And you don't have to implement them, it has already been done for you.

I highly recommend the Artem XmlProvider suite hosted on codeplex.

I use them a lot for demos and samples and totally vouch for them.

http://aspnetxmlproviders.codeplex.com/